# Gibbs Sampling error: parallel_iterations must be a positive integer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying a tensorflow code from [github](https://github.com/dshieble/Music_RBM/blob/master/rbm_chords.py). However, I encounter a problem in the gibbs sampling section.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

def gibbs_sample(k):
    #Runs a k-step gibbs chain to sample from the probability distribution of the RBM defined by W, bh, bv
    def gibbs_step(count, k, xk):
        #Runs a single gibbs step. The visible values are initialized to xk
        hk = sample(tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(xk, W) + bh)) #Propagate the visible values to sample the hidden values
        xk = sample(tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(hk, tf.transpose(W)) + bv)) #Propagate the hidden values to sample the visible values
        return count+1, k, xk

    #Run gibbs steps for k iterations
    ct = tf.constant(0) #counter
    [_, _, x_sample] = control_flow_ops.while_loop(lambda count, num_iter, *args: count < num_iter,
                                         gibbs_step, [ct, tf.constant(k), x], 1, False)
    #This is not strictly necessary in this implementation, but if you want to adapt this code to use one of TensorFlow's
    #optimizers, you need this in order to stop tensorflow from propagating gradients back through the gibbs step
    x_sample = tf.stop_gradient(x_sample) 
    return x_sample

x  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2340], name="x") #The placeholder variable that holds our data
x_sample = gibbs_sample(1)
```

The error comes from the control_flow_ops.while_loop

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-3bb5ef935182> in <module>()
----> 1 x_sample = gibbs_sample(1)

<ipython-input-2-426df97982ef> in gibbs_sample(k)
     10     ct = tf.constant(0) #counter
     11     [_, _, x_sample] = control_flow_ops.while_loop(lambda count, num_iter, *args: count < num_iter,
---> 12                                          gibbs_step, [ct, tf.constant(k), x], 1, False)
     13     #This is not strictly necessary in this implementation, but if you want to adapt this code to use one of TensorFlow's
     14     #optimizers, you need this in order to stop tensorflow from propagating gradients back through the gibbs step

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name, maximum_iterations)
   3051       raise TypeError("body must be callable.")
   3052     if parallel_iterations < 1:
-> 3053       raise TypeError("parallel_iterations must be a positive integer.")
   3054 
   3055     if maximum_iterations is not None:

TypeError: parallel_iterations must be a positive integer.
```

I know that the problem is related to multiple iterations running in parallel, according to github discussion.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1984

> while_loop implements non-strict semantics. An iteration can start as
>   soon as one of the ops for this iteration is ready (i.e., all its
>   inputs are available.) for execution. So a while_loop can easily have
>   multiple iterations running in parallel. For example, for scan, even
>   if the accumulated value is not available in a step, the step can
>   still start and execute any ops that don't depend on the accumulated
>   value. One problem to allow multiple iterations to run in parallel is
>   resource management. parallel_iterations is introduced to give users
>   some control of memory consumption and execution order.

Despite knowing the problems behind it, I am unable to fix the code due to inexperience in gibbs sampling and the control_flow_ops modules. Can anyone who are familiar with gibbs sampling and the control_flow_ops help me to fix the gibbs function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line of code

```
    [_, _, x_sample] = control_flow_ops.while_loop(lambda count, num_iter, *args: count < num_iter, gibbs_step, [ct, tf.constant(k), x], 1, False)
```

the argument "false" you're passing last in the call to tf.while_loop is being interpreted as the parallel_iterations argument. I think you intended to do the following instead:

```
    [_, _, x_sample] = control_flow_ops.while_loop(lambda count, num_iter, *args: count < num_iter, gibbs_step, [ct, tf.constant(k), x])
```